# how to find out series is divergent or convergent for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

\begin{equation}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n^2}\end{equation}

The text book says the above series diverges by the n-th term test, but given no procedures how it was done so, could you some enlighten me, thanks.

---

edit:
it diverges, that was a typo on me.

Comment: If the textbook really says that, you need a new textbook.

Comment: Or apparently OP just wrote "converges" instead of "diverges" which of course changes everything.

Answer (score 2):

For $n \geq 4$ we have $2^n \geq n^2$ such that

$\displaystyle\qquad 
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n^2} \geq \sum_{n=4}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n^2} \geq \sum_{n=4} 1 = +\infty$

making good use of the comparison test.

Comment: is that the nth term test?

Answer (score 2):

A necessary condition for the convergence of a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is that $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=0}$, but $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}}\frac{2^n}{n^2}=\displaystyle{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}}\frac{e^{n\ln 2}}{n^2}=\infty$.

Hence $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{2^n}{n^2}}}$ diverges.

Comment: how do you determine that e^n ln2 / n^2 diverges?

Comment: From L'Hopital Rule. Or using the series expansion for $e^x$.

Comment: The first thing to check! +1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can use the [ration test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test).

$$L = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|.$$

The ratio test states that:

```
if L < 1 then the series converges absolutely;
if L > 1 then the series does not converge;
if L = 1 or the limit fails to exist, 
         then the test is inconclusive, because there exist both convergent 
         and divergent series that satisfy this case.
```

Answer (score 0):

It diverges. First you can prove by induction that: $2^n > n^3$ for $\forall n \geq 10$. So:
$\dfrac{2^n}{n^2} > n$. Thus $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2^n}{n^2} \geq \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty n = +\infty$. So: $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2^n}{n^2} = +\infty$